# javascript this.nombre is not defined

Tags: javascript, variables

```
var Animal = function () {
    var sThis = this;  
    this.nombre = 'juan';
    getNombre = function () {
        return sThis.nombre;
    }
    return {
        getNombre: getNombre
    }
};



 var Animal = function () {
        var sThis = this;  
        this.nombre = 'juan';
        getNombre = function () {
            return this.nombre;
        }
        return {
            getNombre: getNombre
        }
    };

    var scooby = new Animal("Scooby");

    alert(scooby.getNombre());
```

Because when I use this.name instead of using sThis.name tells me that it is not defined, in the code it works first but in the second it doesn't work

Comment: what a curious way of creating an object... you should first define the getNombre function directly in your return statement.

Comment: Because getNombre function has its own scope, if you need this function to be in parent object's scope use => arrow function, or .bind() or just pass "this" as reference in parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const
  Animal = function () {
    this.nombre = 'juan';
    return { getNombre: () => this.nombre };
  },
  scooby = new Animal('Scooby');

alert(scooby.getNombre());
```

---

Arrow functions have no scope, so they keep `this`. Regular function has its own `this`, so it is less ideally for this purpose.

If for some reason you have to use `ES5`, you can rewrite your function as follows:

```
getNombre = (function () {
    return this.nombre
}).bind(this);
```

Note that starting with the `ES 2020` version, private members can be used in classes, so your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
class Animal {
  #nombre = 'juan';   
  get nombre () { return this.nombre };
};

const scooby = new Animal('Scooby');

alert(scooby.nombre);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of **this** is based on how the function is called, not where it's defined.

In your case, you are returning a new object:

```
{ getNombre: getNombre }
```

and if you console.log **scooby**

you'll see something like:

```
{ getNombre: function()...}
```

change your code to:

```
var Animal = function () {
   this.nombre = 'juan';
   this.getNombre = function () {
      return this.nombre;
   }
};
```

or if you don't want to expose this.nombre as object property of **scooby** - aka keep it private, you can do:

```
var Animal = function () {
  this.nombre = 'juan';
  this.getNombre = function () {
    return this.nombre;
  }

  return {
    getNombre: () => this.getNombre()
  }
};
```

or the Arrow function way:

```
var Animal = function () {
   this.nombre = 'juan';
   this.getNombre = () => {
     return this.nombre;
   }
};
```

The difference is: in traditional functions, this get's the reference of the execution context from where it's called, whereas with ES6 Arrow functions it gets the reference of the execution context of where it's defined.

Or in your case, since it seems you don't want **this.nombre** to be accessed (keep it private) you can even do:

```
var Animal = function () {
   var nombre = 'juan';

   this.getNombre = function () {
      return nombre;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Animal = function ()` has no arguments. so `var scooby = new Animal("Scooby");` is nonsens!

you need to use a class constructor

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(nombre) {
    this._nombre = nombre
  }
  get nombre() {
    return this._nombre
  }
}
scooby = new Animal('Scooby');

console.log( 'scooby.nombre =', scooby.nombre )
```